# nextjs trying to pass current url to share on social media

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've created a helper function to generate urls for me like this

```
  function generateUrl(platform: string) {
  const currentUrl = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.href : ''
  switch (platform) {
    case 'facebook':
      return `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${currentUrl}`
    default:
      return ''
  }
}
```

When I console log this its all working fine and I get the expected result, when I bundle this up into an Link/a tag within the app, it returns just the url without `currentUrl` so it just sends me to `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=` without url at the end ? Could it be cause window is not defined yet ?

Comment: Can you please show the full code where you're using this function? But in general, if things depend on `window` being present you'd want to move the logic into a `useEffect` so it only happens on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling/defining generateUrl?

Window could be undefinded.

Do a console.log(currentUrl) above the switch statement, see what it prints.

Comment: Just done a console log on currentUrl above switch statement and it prints the url perfectly fine

Comment: I've got an array like this `const socials = ['Facebook']` and I just map over it like this `socials.map((social, idx) => {
return <Link href={generateUrl(social)}><div>{social}</div></Link>
})`

Comment: try doing :href="generateUrl(social)"